# UserDefaults.standard refusing a closed set of parentheses after it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am watching a video on Udemy for Swift 3 iOS development. The guy has me put:

```
let numberObject = UserDefaults.standard().object(forKey: "number"
```

Xcode says that it is an error to have the parentheses. Is this a new update for Swift that I did not notice?

Comment: A very quick and easy way to figure it out yourself: ⌘-click on `UserDefaults` and take a look at the declaration line of `standard`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your are talking about the parentheses after `standard`, yes, that is a problem. `standard` is a class property, not a method. So there are no parentheses. It is declared as:

```
class var standard: UserDefaults { get }
```

And you are missing the close parentheses at the very end (that may be a typo in your question).

So it should be:

```
let numberObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "number")
```

Back in Swift 1 & 2, it was a method so you needed the parentheses:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.1 it should be.

```
let numberObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "number")
```